# Create multidimensional arrays from a text box to compare and merge their details

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array, array-merge

I’ve been trying to compare a block of lines for a few days now and still haven't found a solution. Actually, it seems that I can't split an array in a multidimensional array. I’ll give you full details should anyone know a better solution and would like to share it.

I have an html page including a textbox where I load data I want to use. It calls several action in an external javascript file to show executed data in three spans, here is a demo:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="..\..\..\css\style.css">
<script type="text/javaScript" src="..\..\js\javaction.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<span id='CHANGINGvalue'><textarea rows="4" cols="20" id="loadingTEXTboxDATA" name="saveIT" onkeyup="actionJAVA1(document.getElementById('CHANGINGvalue'));actionJAVA2(document.getElementById('CHANGINGvalue'));" value="">load data inside this text box</textarea><div class="tooltipRIGHT">&#x1F6C8;<span class="tooltiptext">load data inside this text box</span></div></br></span>
    
<span id='showAREAdata1'>sss</span><br><br>
<span id='showAREAdata2'>ccc</span><br><br>
<span id='showAREAdata3'>hhh</span><br>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my javaction.js file:

```
function actionJAVA1(val)
{
var startingDATA = val.value;
if (startingDATA.includes("text to trigger action")) {
// first block of text to search trough
var i= 0;
var bloccoPERlinee = val.value.split("\n");
for ( i = 0; i < bloccoPERlinee.length; ++i)    
{ 
if (bloccoPERlinee[i].includes('specific text search 1')) 
{
// Yes, it's there
}
else    {
//  block of code to be executed if the condition is false      
bloccoPERlinee[i] = ""
}
}               
var SBLOCCOlinee1 = bloccoPERlinee.join("\n"); 
const removeEmptyLines = SBLOCCOlinee1.split(/\r?\n/).filter(line => line.trim() !== '').join('\n');
var eSEfunzionaLOpotevoTROVAREprima = removeEmptyLines.split('\n').filter(function (s) { return s.match('filtering word to eclude') })                                                                                                                                                                  
var l = 0;
for ( l = 0; l < eSEfunzionaLOpotevoTROVAREprima.length; ++l)   
{ 
eSEfunzionaLOpotevoTROVAREprima[l] = eSEfunzionaLOpotevoTROVAREprima[l].split('permit');
eSEfunzionaLOpotevoTROVAREprima[l] = eSEfunzionaLOpotevoTROVAREprima[l][1]
}
var ANCORAnonSOgestireARRAYmultilinea = eSEfunzionaLOpotevoTROVAREprima.join("\n");                                                                 
document.getElementById('showAREAdata1').innerText = ANCORAnonSOgestireARRAYmultilinea;         
// second block of text to search trough
var x= 0;
var bloccoPERlinee2 = val.value.split("\n");                                            
for ( x = 0; x < bloccoPERlinee2.length; ++x)                                                                                                   
{                                                                                                                                                               
if (bloccoPERlinee2[x].includes('alternative text to search trough')) 
{
// Yes, it's there                                                                                                                                                                                      
}                                                                                                                                                                               
else    {
//  block of code to be executed if the condition is false      
bloccoPERlinee2[x] = ""
 }                              
 }
var SBLOCCOlinee2 = bloccoPERlinee2.join("\n");
const removeEmptyLines2 = SBLOCCOlinee2.split(/\r?\n/).filter(line => line.trim() !== '').join('\n');                                                           
var senzaCOMMENTI = removeEmptyLines2.split("\n");                                                                                      
document.getElementById('showAREAdata2').innerText = senzaCOMMENTI;
```

So far so good: I correctly managed to find the data I want that mainly are numeric value occurring in a different format and details in both arrays coming out from first (array1 named ANCORAnonSOgestireARRAYmultilinea) and second filtering actions (array2 named senzaCOMMENTI).

Besides that I do expect that in array1 should be just one match for any line in array 2, I now should compare them and merge matching data to show in span "showAREAdata3".

I thought to split them getting multdimensional array and if any value show up in both lines from array1 and array2 I should add at line value from arra1 last value from matching line  in array2.

I start declaring a clone from those array and then trying to split array1 value by line and by given characters that in this case is a slash / but I managed to make it work just one per time. At second split it stop to work and the whole java function crash.

On array2 which should be even easier since it already comes in an array and I just should split by blank space to get multidimensional array is actually worse: I can not do it: it also crash the whole java function.

That’s in the specific what I tried in this last case:

```
var senzaCOMMENTIa = structuredClone(senzaCOMMENTI);
var senzaCOMMENTIa = Array.from(senzaCOMMENTIa);
const myArray = senzaCOMMENTIa.split(" ");}}
```

I may think to use map or for each – and I also tried a few solutions but did not succeded.

In the comments Swiffy asked for an example of how the input and outputs should be:

text box : mult line pasted text from external source
[

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec ut velit eget arcu eleifend consequat. Suspendisse tempor ut tellus ut fermentum. Donec sed euismod felis. Fusce venenatis viverra metus quis elementum. Etiam diam sapien, dignissim eget auctor a, bibendum vel nulla. Morbi non vulputate quam. Ut commodo venenatis ultrices. Phasellus a diam ultricies, iaculis enim at, lobortis nibh. Proin sodales tristique quam. Vivamus ornare sollicitudin mi, nec tincidunt neque mollis eget. Vivamus fermentum cursus felis, id pulvinar magna semper non. Duis id eros in massa dictum maximus. Nullam mollis risus non ligula consectetur, vel interdum massa laoreet. Aliquam nec finibus ex.

Praesent pretium hendrerit urna in finibus. Sed lacus ex, pharetra sed leo sed, molestie ultricies turpis. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas dictum viverra fermentum. Donec tincidunt libero tortor. Pellentesque facilisis, urna id viverra volutpat, massa erat finibus urna, sit amet rutrum felis lectus eu ex. Maecenas tincidunt orci molestie turpis ullamcorper, non feugiat felis tempus. Fusce rutrum urna sit amet mattis suscipit. Aliquam non sem sollicitudin, lacinia orci sit amet, finibus nisi. Mauris sollicitudin massa non massa sollicitudin pellentesque. Duis finibus ipsum et molestie tempor.


   
    Maecenas 
line1dataA/line1dataB
    tempus 
line2dataC/line2dataD data3b
    . Vestibulum 
line3dataE/line3dataF
    
    Sed efficitur lorem vitae orci 
    data1a data2a data 3a(occasional) data4a
    tincidunt volutpat. 
    data1b data2b data3b
data1c data2c data3c(occasional) data3d
Sed volutpat velit ut neque varius gravida a et elit. Ut egestas diam in urna varius, at volutpat mi rutrum. Sed dictum venenatis arcu, sit amet maximus tellus egestas vitae. Sed condimentum orci ac dolor dictum cursus. Suspendisse et eros velit. Donec rhoncus purus ex, nec volutpat elit viverra a. Integer efficitur non nibh eget congue.

Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Morbi hendrerit bibendum lectus, at convallis sem cursus vel. Aliquam nec sem scelerisque, tempor elit sed, lacinia augue. Duis ex ipsum, tempus non placerat non, eleifend maximus est. Suspendisse sodales nulla a quam euismod, in tincidunt elit venenatis. Cras interdum vitae felis at vestibulum. Integer ac est ultricies, tincidunt ipsum in, tempor eros. Vivamus ultrices massa eleifend viverra auctor. 
]
```

while being the array I've already found fro array1 such as:

```
array1: [line1dataA/line1dataB
        line2dataC/line1dataD,
        line3dataE/line3dataF,
        so on,]
```

and for array2 such as:

```
array2: [data1a data2a data 3a(occasional) data4a, data1b data2b data3b, data1c data2c data3c(occasional) data4c, so on]
```

result of comparision:

```
line1dataA/line1dataB data4a
line2dataC/line2dataD data3b
line3dataE/line3dataF data4c
so on
```

Comment: I'll be honest with you; your code is pretty hard to read. The most valuable thing you could add to your question is a simple example of what text goes inside a textbox and what should the correct output look like.

Comment: @Swiffy thanks for your comment, trief it and honestly whe i wrote initial question thought: it really is so hard to format questions? didn't remembered.... hope the hints I gave may helps, jsut tell me if may be done something else

Comment: Some hints to improve the question: (1) remove all the dependency on HTML and document. Your problem description is about arrays, for which no interaction with the DOM should be relevant. (2) Use descriptive variable names in English (3) properly indent your code. (4) Turn your code in a Stack Snippet using the toolbar (5) Make sure the snippet is runnable without errors and outputs something with `console.log` (6) add the *expected* output and how it differs from the actual output of that runnable snippet.

Comment: @trincot thanks for your suggetions, I already tried to indent in the beginning but it was not accepted fomr the parser. 
console log is actually document.getElementById('showAREAdata1').innerText = ANCORAnonSOgestireARRAYmultilinea;        
how to add a snippet?

Comment: Thanks for adding input and output example. Unfortunately the example you added is still lacking some details. I need to know what exactly "pasted text from external source" looks like and you should be more specific with the array examples. Please make valid examples like `var input = "some input text"` and `var output = ["text", "text2"]` as something like `[ddd rrrrr xxx gggg, bbbb oooo sss lll, mmmmm hhhhh kkk ttt, so on]` is not a valid array.

Comment: @Swiffy I tried to give you an example using standard "lorem ipsum " randome text generator
hope it is useful, I do really thanks you for your effort even if it would not come to a solution, just to let you know

Comment: Wait are you looking to make a text diffing program? Example here: https://i.imgur.com/DFeXvZ2.png

Comment: @Swiffy it may seems but actually I need a line separated answer merging just one data details more from array1 extraction coming from array2

Comment: Do you want every word of the input text into an array? Like if input text is `"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec ut velit eget arcu eleifend consequat."`, the resulting array would be `let arr = ['Lorem', 'ipsum', 'dolor', 'sit', 'amet,', 'consectetur', 'adipiscing', 'elit.', 'Donec', 'ut', 'velit', 'eget', 'arcu', 'eleifend', 'consequat.']`

Comment: no, I just need it on any line, is that I use to post questions on really much simpler issues, I  dont't really know how to go on differente lines, my effort to achieva an html text like : "Maecenas</br> line1dataA/line1dataB tempus </br>line2dataC/line2dataD data3b</br> . Vestibulum line3dataE/line3dataF</br>" or "Sed efficitur lorem vitae orci</br> data1a data2a data 3a(occasional) data4a </br>tincidunt volutpat. </br>data1b data2b data3b</br> data1c data2c data3c(occasional) data3d</br> Sed volutpat ve</br>"was somehow ridicolous, I know. are you able to understando and did it from scratch?

Comment: Please use appropriate tabbing in your code.

Comment: @LeeTaylor as I've already commented I would like becouse I understand it is a waste of time to read through and I regret to wast your time but the parser do not allow me to use [tab] and post it. If there is a way to send an attachment I'd do but i see no